# Hover over list item to reveal hidden element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a UL and each LI when hovered over needs to reveal a "Remove" link/button.

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/dPKZQv

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="editor-row">
                        <ul class="skyPad-attachments">
                            <li>
                                <a class="link-ico-attachment ico-image-attach rowHook" href="#">
                                    a-jacobs-weeklyProgress.pdf
                                    <span class="link-remove ico-remove removeHook">Remove</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="link-ico-attachment ico-doc-attach rowHook" href="#">
                                    a-jacobs-weeklyProgress.pdf
                                    <span class="link-remove ico-remove removeHook">Remove</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var row = $('.rowHook'),
    remove = $('.removeHook'),
    reveal = $('.revealHook');


    remove.hide();

row.on('mouseover' , function(){
      if(row.children('span').hasClass('removeHook')) {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      }
    });
```

Even if this current function requires a slight modification I can't seem to wrap my head around as to how you would trigger the "Mouseleave" event to .hide() the "remove".

Here is a 1-minute screen cast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCq9YVEi3BM

Thank you to anyone that takes the time to help me understand.

Comment: `mouseleave` is `mouseout`, ex: http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/   This page of documentation does exactly what you want, I think. So give it a look. The bottom portion of it for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make one small change.

Change:

```
$(this).fadeIn();
```

to:

```
$(this).find('span').fadeIn();
```

`$(this)` in `$(this).fadeIn();` referes to the link, but you want to fade in the child span.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g3dom4yz/)**

Comment: Thank you! Here is what I used for mouseleave  row.on('mouseleave' , function(){
      if(row.children('span').hasClass('removeHook')) {
        $(this).find('span').fadeOut();
      }

Comment: Sorry Stack if that's not right of me to put code in comments. Does anyone know if it's proper stack etiquette to update my errors with the correct answer to help others that might find this question?

Comment: That's fine. You should surround code in comments with backticks so it gets formatted like code.

Comment: Excellent tip, will do going forward.